# syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: Error: Type 'PanAxis' not found. interactive_scroll_viewer.dart:59 final PanAxis panAxis;

Tags: flutter, pdf, crash

I using `flutter 3.3.5` version and `syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: 20.3.58`. it was working perfectly in past weeks, but now i'm getting this error

```
: Error: Type 'PanAxis' not found.
interactive_scroll_viewer.dart:59
  final PanAxis panAxis;
        ^^^^^^^
: Error: Undefined name 'PanAxis'.
interactive_scroll_viewer.dart:15
      this.panAxis = PanAxis.free,
                     ^^^^^^^
: Error: 'PanAxis' isn't a type.
interactive_scroll_viewer.dart:59
  final PanAxis panAxis;
        ^^^^^^^
: Error: No named parameter with the name 'panAxis'.
interactive_scroll_viewer.dart:299
        panAxis: widget.panAxis,
        ^^^^^^^
: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
interactive_viewer.dart:61
  InteractiveViewer({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

i change my flutter version into `3.7.0`, project build successfully built, but app crashes on when user navigate to the pdf screen. please help how to fix this error.